# Powershell - Append text to each line of output

Tags: powershell

I think I'm missing something simple.
I need to append text to each line of output from a Get-ChildItem instruction.

As a simplistic example, picture adding a reference number ('12345') to a folder listing on c:

The output I'm after would look something vaguely like:

```
c:\Program Files 12345
c:\program Files (x86) 12345
c:\temp 12345
c:\Users 12345
c:\Windows 12345
...etc
```

The real application has more to it, but the end result is that a Powershell script runs a bunch of these commands with some metadata appended to each line which then gets pulled into Excel for reporting.

I just can't figure how to add the string to each line...

Comment: Excel sounds like CSV. If so do it the proper way and use Export-Csv and give it a data structure to export. Otherwise what did you try to make it happen? A simple string concatenation would work as well or just using an output function with the right quotation marks and argument.

Comment: I said it was probably simple - string concatenation would almost certainly do the trick but I'm missing how to do that for every line of output

Comment: This might give you a start `gci c:\ -Directory -Recurse | select fullname, {'12345'}`

Comment: Or if you prefer strings (you shouldn't) perhaps this `gci c:\ -Directory -Recurse | select {"$($_.fullname) 12345"}`

Comment: A loop would also work. `1..10 | %{ ("ABC $_") }`. If you plan to generate a CSV you should use a proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the numbers trailing directly to the folder names you can:

```
gci C:\ -Directory | % { $_.FullName + " 12345"}
```

More complex with a calculated property

```
(gci c:\ -Directory | select @{n='WithText';e={$_.FullName + " 12345"}}).WithText
```